# location sensor simulator activating "Save map points"

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a question regarding location sensor simulator (that is distributed with mango update).

How can I activate the "Save map points" button??  Whatever I try, it's always disabled.

**Update**: The problem was in using beta tools. Installing the latest RC version resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the **Live** button off.